# postgres all elements of array in column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an `array['a', 'b', 'c']`

Very simply I want to check whether all elements of the above array exist in a column say `test` of a table `t`.

It would be best if the sql return boolean.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I have done it in the following way

```
SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT test) @> ARRAY ['a', 'b', 'c']::varchar[] FROM t;
```

please do suggest if there is other optimum way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

You can use Postgresql [UNNEST](https://hevodata.com/learn/postgresql-unnest/) function and [EXCEPT](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-except/) function, it is more optimal if your array is large.

```
SELECT DISTINCT test from unnest(ARRAY['a', 'b', 'c']) AS data(test)
EXCEPT
SELECT DISTINCT test from t
```